# How to enable php_redis.dll on windows / wamp?

Tags: php, redis

I am new in redis and I would like to know if it is possible to use the `php_redis.dll` on PHP 5.3 WAMP? I would like to develop a site by using my redis instance on redis to go just using redis extension.

I have loaded the php_redis.dll — phpredis 2.1.3 (PHP 5.3.6, win32,...

And it do show in the wamp PHP extensions as loaded or checked but I still missing out something because I still encounter this error below:

> Fatal error: Class 'Redis' not found in
>   C:\wamp\www\api.twitterapp.com\1redistest.php on line 7

Answer (score 4):

1. Check out your `php version` and know whether `thread safety` is enabled or not (by using `phpinfo()`)

   tip: Thread Safe = `ts`, Non-Thread Safe = `nts`
2. Now we need to download the `php_redis.dll`. Follow the DLL link on the https://pecl.php.net/package/redis page.(Download as per PHP Version and thread based)
3. Extract the zip file
4. Copy the `php_redis.dll` and paste to following folder in Wamp Server(`wamp\bin\php\php5.x.xx\ext\`)
5. Add the `extension=php_redis.dll` in your `php.ini`
6. Re-start the wamp Server
7. Do `phpinfo()` and search **redis**. It will start displaying which means its **Redis is installed**

**For check redis is installed Or Not try following code:**

```php
try {
    $redis = new Redis();
    $redis->connect('localhost', 6379);
    $redis->set('name', 'Redis is Installed');
    echo $glueStatus = $redis->get('name');
    
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe will be better use a client library instead a php extension, because the shared hostings dont contain this extension, take a look at

[Which PHP module to use with redis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001075/which-php-module-to-use-with-redis)

Comment: yeah but if my understanding is correct.. according to the benchmark on http://dev.af83.com/af83-open-source-projects/which-php-library-use-redis-benchmark/2011/01/01 .. php_redis is better than other php libraries

Comment: yeah, but the article was from jan-2011 and as far i know all the libraries are under active development, you expect to have much trafic on your site?

Comment: oh did not saw the date my apologies, no im just testing around .. the reason i like phpredis against others its because its the outcome of my recent research